# Div overlapping & wrong height

Tags: html, overlap

I have 3 DIVs. 2 are inside the parent DIV. something like

```
<div id="parent">    
    <div id=1>......</div>    
    <div id=2 style="position:relative;left:0px;top:-300px;">....</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is an overlapping. The annoying thing is, the parent div has a huge white space at the bottom. The reason apparently is because the parent div doesn't minus the overlapping.

Would you please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Andrew's answer a bit for clarity. If you use `position:relative` the space that element would take up on the page is preserved(the white space you are seeing) and then the element is moved.

With `position:absolute`, the space that element would have taken up is not used("removed from the flow of the page"). However, with `position:absolute`, the element will not be bound inside the parent div anymore either unless declaring the parent div with a `position:relative;top:0;left:0;` CSS declaration.

So you would want something like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;">    
    <div id=1>......</div>    
    <div id=2 style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:-300px;">....</div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps to clarify a little bit. Still not sure if this will give you the exact look you are going for, but from a CSS rule perspective it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` to remove the element from the flow of the page .