# CSS: Parent div with overlapping child div - can't get parent height right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Image of overlapping div]

I'm trying to eliminate the extra space in the **`#middle-panel`** underneath the **`.box-label`** text, but I need to maintain the functionality of the **`#middle-panel`** expanding when I get to smaller screen sizes and the text becomes stacked.  But if I set a specific height on the **`#middle-panel`** to eliminate the extra space, it no longer expands to accommodate the stacked type.

This fiddle shows my current implementation:
**[Current Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73auc3Lh/)**

If, in the fiddle, you add **`height: 65px;`** to the **`#middle-panel-inner-div`**, you will see the desired amount of space below the text.  Unfortunately, if you then change the **`width:`** of the **`.red-box-and-label`** class from 25% to 20% (to represent what will happen at smaller screen sizes), you will see the text becomes stacked, but the **`#middle-panel`** doesn't expand to accommodate it. Delete the just-added **`height: 65px;`** and you will see that the **`#middle-panel`** has now expanded to accommodate the text, but once again with too much space on the bottom.

I've tried some solutions, such as: [Div overlapping & wrong height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924522/div-overlapping-wrong-height)
but none of them seem to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *when we get on smaller screen sizes* and luckily you use a fixed 600px width for #main...

Comment: I used fixed width just for the fiddle, since the width settings aren't contributing to the problem.  In actuality, I use 100% widths for the panels and main (plus media queries, etc.).  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing is happens because height is `auto` and parent div expand height depend on child div. So it takes it's child div height. Even though you give negative `top` value.

The solution of this issue is,  remove negative `top` value and give `margin-top` to `.red-box-and-label`

Remove `top: -30px;` from  `#middle-panel-inner-div`. And:

```
.red-box-and-label {
    margin: -30px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
}
```

**[Updated Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73auc3Lh/5/)**

Comment: This works great!  Can you help me understand why `margin: -30px 0 0;` on `.red-box-and-label` works, but giving this margin to `#middle-panel-inner-div` instead doesn't?

Comment: @eggroll As i explain in answer. Relative position take space in page layout even it display `top:-30px;`. While in margin, content and space both shifted

Comment: Right, but if I delete `position: relative` from `#middle-panel-inner-div` and give it the negative top margin (`margin: -30px 0 0`, not `top: -30`) instead of giving that margin setting to `.red-box-and-label`, the negative margin is ignored.  Once I've deleted `position: relative` from `#middle-panel-inner-div` what is still different about it that it doesn't behave/render the same way as `.red-box-and-label`, i.e. it's not shifted up 30px?

Comment: @eggroll negative top margin  is work if you remove `position:relative` but not shift the object from it's position because position is not given.
Check https://jsfiddle.net/73auc3Lh/10/. Use firebug plugins to Check it.  Also check: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd need an inner wrapper for the `#middle-panel-inner-div` with a negative `bottom-margin` to compensate for the `30px` you moved the boxes up with. But if you place it, you'd have to move all the `flex` properties from `#middle-panel-inner-div` to the inner wrapper. So it's easier to just make an outer wrapper for it, move the `top:-30px; position:relative` to it and add the `margin-bottom: -30px` to `#middle-panel-inner-div`.

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/73auc3Lh/8/).

Notice the change in markup and the relevant CSS code:

```
.aWrapper {
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}
#middle-panel-inner-div {
  /* top: -30px */
  /* position: relative */
  margin: 0 auto -30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrei, this works great, too! As ketan's solution is ever-so-slightly simpler, is there a scenario you can think of that might make your solution the better way for me to go?

Comment: Yes. His solution solves the problem by applying the `-30px` margin on the contents of `#middle-panel-inner-div`. If that content ever wraps, all rows will have the distance to the row above shortened by `30px`. My solution would have applied the margin only on the container, not touching the contents. If they never wrap, you're fine.

Comment: Awesome! My contents will never wrap, so ketan's solution will work.  But I asked in case there was something I was unaware of, like exactly what you describe, so that when I do need something like that (i.e. my contents do wrap), I'll be able to apply your solution. Thanks, Andrei!!  I'll definitely upvote your responses once I have the reputation :-)